# Check whether in NERDTree

Tags: vim, nerdtree, viml

NerdTree docs says that to toggle maximize(zoom) and minimize the NERDTree, `Shift-a` is the key.

I have my .vimrc configured for regular split pane maximize/mini

```
let mapleader="<\Space>"
nnoremap <leader>- :wincmd _<cr>:wincmd \|<cr>
nnoremap <leader>= :wincmd =<cr>
```

So basically to zoom a regular window in vim, I press `Space -` and to zoom out `Space +` but this doesn't behave nicely when NERDTree is on. When NERDTree is on and I do `Space -` it zooms in, but when I press `Space +` it doesn't zoom out anymore, equally true both for the code window and the NERDTree window.

Answer (score 0):

Very probably with

```
        exists("loaded_nerd_tree")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if it's open anywhere

```
if bufwinnr("NERD_tree_2") == 1
  " something
else
```

Check if cursor is inside nerdtree

```
if bufname("") == "NERD_tree_2"
  " something
else
```